# SQL - Transform GETDATE() into the exactly hour

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, getdate

I've this:

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

Which gives me :

```
2017-06-12 16:51:50.410
```

How can I convert this in order to get:

```
2017-06-12 16:00:00.000
```

I've some processes and I'm registering the date and hour of the job but I only want the exactly hour.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get `getdate()` truncated to hour:

```
select dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, getdate() ), 0)
```

This adds the number of hours since `1900-01-01` to the date `1900-01-01`.

You can also swap `hour` for other levels of truncation: year, quarter, month, day, minute, second, et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most human-readable solution is:

```
SELECT convert(datetime,FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00.000'))
```

- FORMAT to get the GETDATE timestamp exactly how you want it.
- CONVERT to ensure the data type is a datetime.

Comment: hh is a 12 hour clock, so 13:00 would be 1AM

Comment: thanks John. updated to from hh to HH for the 24 hour clock.

Comment: No worries.  Just didn't want OP to  get unexpected results.  Moot point.  Looks like we both got downvoted.  Format() is a valid solution if used in a responsible manner.  Many folks don't see it like that